# Sitecore 9.3 - parts of CM stopped working, JavaScript errors in console

Tags: content-management, javascript, development

It seems that any place the Sitecore CM where a modal dialog would pop up has stopped working and I haven't been able to figure out why. I see the same behavior in both Chrome and FireFox.  The error description is a bit more descriptive in FireFox:

> Uncaught TypeError: top._scDialogs is undefined.  It seems both
> jsnlog.js and sitecore.js are trying to call that undefined function.

It appears that dragging and dropping is also broken and I see messages in the Console about `scDraggable` not being defined as well.

[image: Package Designer error in console after clicking Items Statically]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

I've tried rebuilding and re-deploying.  The same codebase is working correctly on our QA environment. The environment that has this issue is DEV environment.

Comment: Check your network tab. Are you getting 404's on some JS files?

Comment: I am not get any 404s, no.